# static float * myVar initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, static, initialization

Using C++, I declared the following static variable in a class **SavingsAccount**

```
static float *waitingInQueue;
```

But I'm not able to initialize the data pointed, I'm only able to initialize the address of the pointer as follows : `float* SavingsAccount::waitingInQueue=0;`

I would like the data of this pointer initialized at 0. I don't want to use a setter because I need to be able to initialized it once without using an object of the class SavingsAccount. I would like to do the following statement outside a function : `*waitingInQueue=0;`

Here is my header file :

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H

class SavingsAccount
{
public:
    SavingsAccount();  
    float getInterestDue(){return *interestDue;};
    float getAmountDue() {return *amountDue;};
    int getArrivalTime() {return *arrivalTime;};
    int getFinishTime() {return *finishTime;};
    void setFinishTime(int newTime) {*finishTime=newTime;};
    float computeInterestDue();
    // compute the interest due... 
    float computeAmountDue();
    // compute the total amount due
    void waitingClient();
    // increment *arrivalTime
    void waitingProcess();
    // increment *finishTime checking if there is not another client already processing, in that case make him wait during the previous client processing
    void display();
    // display the information about 1 client
    void saveAccounts();
    // save the information of the 20 clients
    // void setWaitingInQueue(float x) {*waitingInQueue=x;}; <- can't be used
private:
    float clientTable[8];
    // information about a single client
    static float globalTable[20][8];
    static int clientCount;
    float *customerID;
    static float *arrivalTime;
    static float *finishTime;
    static const float depositType[6];
    float *depositAmount;
    static const float interestRate[12];
    float *interestDue;
    float *amountDue;
    float *PtrDepType, *PtrRate;
    static float *waitingInQueue;
};

#endif  /* SAVINGSACCOUNT_H */
```

Here is my .cpp

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_CPP
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_CPP

#include<cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>  // include to get the number of seconds since 1970 (srand))
#include <iomanip> // to set precision of numbers setprecision()

#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h> // for windows
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // win32      // for unix

#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;

float SavingsAccount::globalTable[20][8];
int SavingsAccount::clientCount=0;
const float SavingsAccount::depositType[6]={0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5};
const float SavingsAccount::interestRate[]={1.71, 1.80, 2.07, 2.25, 2.25, 2.52, 2.70, 3.06, 3.24, 3.69, 3.60, 4.14};
float* SavingsAccount::arrivalTime;
float* SavingsAccount::finishTime;
float* SavingsAccount::waitingInQueue=0; // should be *waitingInQueue = 0;

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount()
{
    clientCount++;
    int index;
    srand(time(NULL));          // 
    index=rand()%6;             // 
    customerID=&clientTable[0];
    arrivalTime=&clientTable[1];
    finishTime=&clientTable[2];
    PtrDepType=&clientTable[3]; // &depositType[index]
    depositAmount=&clientTable[4];
    PtrRate=&clientTable[5]; // &interestRate[N]
    interestDue=&clientTable[6];
    amountDue=&clientTable[7];
    *customerID=clientCount;
    *PtrDepType=depositType[index];
    *depositAmount=(rand()%49+1)*1000;
    if (clientCount<=10) *PtrRate=interestRate[2*index]; // N=2*index
    else *PtrRate=interestRate[2*index+1]; // N=2*index+1
}

float SavingsAccount::computeInterestDue()
{
    *interestDue=*PtrDepType*(*depositAmount)**PtrRate*(1-0.2)/100;
}

float SavingsAccount::computeAmountDue()
{
    *amountDue=*depositAmount+*interestDue;
}

void SavingsAccount::waitingClient()
{
    if (clientCount==1) *arrivalTime=0;
    else {
        int milliseconds=(rand()%6+3)*1000; // random time in milliseconds
        #ifdef WIN32   // for windows
        Sleep(milliseconds);
        #else      // for unix
        usleep(milliseconds * 1000); // nano seconds have to be multiplied by 1000
        #endif // win32
        *arrivalTime = *arrivalTime+milliseconds/1000;

    }
}

void SavingsAccount::waitingProcess()
{
    if(*finishTime < *arrivalTime)
    {
        *waitingInQueue =*arrivalTime-*finishTime;
    }
    int milliseconds=(rand()%6+2)*1000;  // random time in milliseconds
    #ifdef WIN32
    Sleep(milliseconds);
    #else
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
    #endif // win32
    *finishTime= *arrivalTime + milliseconds/1000 + *waitingInQueue;
}

void SavingsAccount::saveAccounts()
{
    globalTable[clientCount-1][0]=*customerID;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][1]=*arrivalTime;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][2]=*finishTime;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][3]=*PtrDepType;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][4]=*depositAmount;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][5]=*PtrRate;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][6]=*interestDue;
    globalTable[clientCount-1][7]=*amountDue;
}

void SavingsAccount::display()
{
    cout << setprecision(0) << setw(4) << right << clientTable[0];
    cout << setprecision(0) << setw(7) << right << clientTable[1];
    cout << setprecision(0) << setw(8) << right << clientTable[2];
    cout << setprecision(2) << setw(10) << right << fixed << clientTable[3];
    cout << setprecision(2) << setw(12) << right << clientTable[4];
    cout << setprecision(2) << setw(7)<< right << clientTable[5];
    cout << setprecision(2) << setw(12)<< right << clientTable[6];
    cout << setprecision(2) << setw(12)<< right << clientTable[7] << endl;
}

#endif
```

The idea of the program is to display information about 20 clients that are arriving every x seconds (3static float *waitingInQueue; to increase the finishing time of all the client if needed.

If you have any other idea to easily simulated a queue I would be interested.

Comment: if you want to get "*waitingInQueue", the address must stores a float var.

Comment: Static members can be initialized by some static init function.

Comment: @kaitian, So should I create an other variable myvar, initilize it to 0 and then in my .cpp : float* SavingsAccount::waitingInQueue=&myvar

Comment: Why not use a STL container for your queue instead of hand-crafting stuff? There is std::dequeue, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `*waitingInQueue = 0;` were valid outside a function, it would be incorrect because you're initializing the pointer to null.

The easiest way to do what you're asking is something like this:

```
class SavingsAccount
{
    ...

private:
    static float zero;
    static float* waitingInQueue;
};

float SavingsAccount::zero = 0.0f;
float SavingsAccount::waitingInQueue = &SavingsAccount::zero;
```

Comment: If I want the variable to be able to change should I just erase the const ?

Comment: Which const? There's no const in the parts of the code in question, but yeah, you can't modify const variables :D

Comment: Let's say that :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: Might be a bit strange if I did `*waitingInQueue=1` and I'd end up with `SavingsAccount::zero==1`. ...

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Yeah, these variables should probable be const.

Comment: Actually i want to be able to change those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your static variable in many different ways -- but you should be asking a different question - "How can I get rid of my static variables?". `static` variables are often a sign that something is not quite right, and in that light I think you have a pretty large design problem here.

I'd group all your static variables into a `Branch` object. Then have each `SavingsAccount` have a pointer to their `Branch`. And add a `newAccount()` to `Branch` for creation. Then you have no more statics and everything is neater (and easier to test).

There also seems to be a lot of uses of pointers where non-pointer types would be OK, and cases where fixed length arrays are used, but would be improved by switching to `std::vector<>`

Comment: Actully I'm just learning about C++ and a part of my subject was to use static variables ^^ I'm sure you're right, but I guess i don't have the competence to do what you are sugesting yet. I will try all your sugestions anyway !